# Selenium Automation Testing

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a webpage with a textbox field. A calender icon near it. When i click on the calender icon a calender view is displayed. 
Its angularjs datepicker. Can anyone provide an example to automate this type of date pickers.
(While the automation proceeds it reaches calender then opens the calender and then automation cannot be proceeded.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the value directly to input box in which date picker value store after selecting the date in date picker

`<input type="text" name="deliveryDate" value="30/07/2015">`

if that is the text box taking date and if u click on that text box it open an date picker, so insted of clicking on text box try to pass the value directly as below

```
webdriver.findelement(by.name("deliveryDate")).sendkeys("30/07/2015");
```